# Does the 2017 edition of The Atlas of Middle-earth contain any new content?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

About two months ago a new edition of *The Atlas of Middle-earth* by Karen Wynn Fonstad was released. This edition changes the title to *The Atlas of Tolkien's Middle-earth*. This is the second time that this title has been used with the book. Other than the title and the new cover, does this edition contain anything that hasn't been in previous editions? Is there any reason to buy the new one?

The ISBNs of a previous edition and the new edition are:

- 9780618126996 (2002)
- 9780008194512 (2017)

Comment: The title change is probably to make clear the distinction with Jackson's Middle-earth, which appears considerably ... smaller.

Comment: Some of the foreign language editions feature redrawn maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

From a redditor who contacted the publisher:

> It is a reprint, **no new info or updates**. I asked the publisher who confirmed this.
>   <sub>([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/6elwzs/the_atlas_of_middleearth/dibc8lp/?context=1))</sub>

It is also worth noting that Karen Fonstad died over twelve years ago.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say for sure, but [AbeBooks.com](https://www.abebooks.com/9780008194512/Atlas-Tolkiens-Middle-earth-Karen-Wynn-0008194513/plp) lists the 2017 edition as a reissue, so I assume there is no new content.

> Title: The Atlas of Tolkien s Middle-earth 
>   Publisher: HarperCollins Publishers, United Kingdom 
>   Publication Date: 2017
>   Binding: Paperback
>   Book Condition:New
>   Edition: Re-issue..

Sadly, Karen Wynn Fonstad died on [March 11, 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Wynn_Fonstad), which means that she could not have contributed any new content for more than 12 years.